# Format String to Date MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

**SCENARIO**

I am trying to migrate data and currently my date value is just a string in the format of `Jun 28, 2001` aka `MMM DD, YYYY` format. I need to convert them into a DateTime object such that it will be displayed as `2001-06-28T00:00:00`

**QUESTION**

I have read about [STR_TO_DATE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) but I am still having trouble understanding it.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using  `'%b %d, %Y'`

```
select str_to_date('Jun 28, 2001', '%b %d, %Y' )
```

and eventually formatting as

```
 select date_format(str_to_date('Jun 28, 2001', '%b %d, %Y' ), '%Y-%m-%dT%T')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this line :-

select str_to_date('Jun 28, 2001', '%b %d, %Y' )

And go through this link to understand :-

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp